# different accuracy settings for `CLLocationManager` in a single app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm developing my first IOS application for iPhone, I need two accuracy settings on the `CLLocationManager`.
In certain application screens I need a `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters` accuracy and in others a need a much precise location like `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.

Should I stop and start the location manager in different parts of the application and change the accuracy parameter?

Can the accuracy be changed on the fly (without stopping/starting the location manager)?

Comment: Yes, it can change on the fly.  You can have multiple instances with different accuracies if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are able to do it "on the fly (without stopping/starting the location manager)." You can start a new location manager in each page that you need different accuracy.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }
```

I know that is not exactly what you want but that is how I do it in one of my apps where I need the same thing.

Comment: Cool, so you can have multiple instances with different settings in a single app.

Comment: you can if they are separate pages and there for have separate .m and .h files